# javax.xml.soap.SOAPException: Unable to parse SOAP document

Tags: java, web-services, soap, wsdl

I'm writing an application to communicate with another application via SOAP web services. I have configured proxy server for my application and sending the SOAP envelope. I am using Axis2. Below is the code:

```
SOAPConnection conn = SOAPConnectionFactoryImpl.newInstance().createConnection();
SOAPMessage sm = conn.call(smsg, endpoint);
```

Where smsg is the SOAPMessage and endpoint is the SOAP endpoint string.

My SOAP envelople is :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
                      <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:x="http://www.xxxx.com/test">
                        <soapenv:Header></soapenv:Header>
                        <soapenv:Body>
                          <x:insert>
                            <opened_by>John</opened_by>
                            <caller_id></caller_id>
                            <category>request</category>
                            <assignment_group>Itil</assignment_group>
                            <contact_type>email</contact_type>
                            <impact>3</impact>
                            <urgency>3</urgency>
                            <state>1</state>
                            <short_description>Request: 7   </short_description>
                            <description>This is test

Source Data:
  type= 
  id= 
  name= 
                            </description>
                          </x:insert>
                        </soapenv:Body>
                      </soapenv:Envelope>
```

I am getting below error:

```
Unable to parse SOAP document
javax.xml.soap.SOAPException: Unable to parse SOAP document
    at org.apache.axis2.saaj.SOAPConnectionImpl.call(SOAPConnectionImpl.java:209)
Caused by: org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Unable to parse SOAP document
    at org.apache.axis2.util.Utils.getInboundFaultFromMessageContext(Utils.java:531)
    at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.handleResponse(OutInAxisOperation.java:375)
    at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.send(OutInAxisOperation.java:421)
    at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.executeImpl(OutInAxisOperation.java:229)
    at org.apache.axis2.client.OperationClient.execute(OperationClient.java:165)
    at org.apache.axis2.saaj.SOAPConnectionImpl.call(SOAPConnectionImpl.java:205)
    ... 82 more
```

Update: There is a proxy configured on the tomcat where application is running.

Comment: Isn't there another Cause exception why it cannot parse soap?

Comment: No, there is no other exception detail.

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar issue once, it was caused by the first line in your soap

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```